# Count duplicate dates in list and occurance of duplicate dates in count

Tags: javascript

I am having list of dates in which i need to check for duplicates and occurances of duplicate dates in count i need to implement in javascript...
Try to help me out 
thank in advance.
`EX: { 12/11/2011, 12/11/2011, 11/4/2012, 12/6/2012, 12/6/2012, 12/6/2012}
Desire output: {12/11/2011, 11/4/2012, 12/6/2012}
count: 12/11/2011 =2
count: 12/6/2012 =3`

Comment: Add an example of your "list of dates" to the question. Then show us what the expected output would look like (removed duplicates with duplicate counts?). Lastly, show us what you have tried to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dates are strings (stored as a string) you can try something like this:

```
var dates = ["12/11/2011", "12/11/2011", "11/4/2012", "12/6/2012", "12/6/2012", "12/6/2012"];
var dates_set = {}; // key will be date, and values will be count

for (var i = dates.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
    var d = dates[i];
    if (dates_set.hasOwnProperty(d)) {  // already is in our set, just increase counter
        dates_set[d] = dates_set[d] + 1;;
    } else { // there is no such date, lets add it
        dates_set[d] = 1
    }

};
document.write(dates_set["12/11/2011"]);
document.write("<br />");
document.write(dates_set["12/6/2012"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce)

> _.reduce(list, iterator, memo, [context]) Aliases: inject, foldl  Also known as inject and foldl, reduce boils down a list of values into a
>   single value. Memo is the initial state of the reduction, and each
>   successive step of it should be returned by iterator.

### [Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/pmy7C/2/)

```
var dates = [ '1/1/2006', '1/1/2006', '1/1/2007', '1/1/2007', '1/1/2007', '1/1/2006', '1/1/2012', '1/1/2006', '1/1/2009', '1/1/2012'];

var x = _.reduce(dates, 
            function(counts, date) {
                counts[date] = (counts[date] || 0) + 1;
                return counts;
            }, {});

alert(JSON.stringify(x));
```

### Produces

```
{"1/1/2006":4,"1/1/2007":3,"1/1/2012":2,"1/1/2009":1}
```

​